# matplotlib - randomly pick N points from 2D array, and plot spatial scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, 2d, surface

I have plots like the following:
[image]

Left Plot : original 100 * 100 numpy data

Right Plot : What I want - randomly choose N data from the original data, and plot them on a surface plot

How can I randomly choose N number of data from the left plot, and plot the chosen data on a scatter plot like the right plot?

I used `ax.imshow(data)` to generate the surface plot on the left. `data` is a 2D numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to colorize the randomly chosen points according to the image you can use the same colormap and normalization for the scatter as you have for the image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

original_data = np.random.rand(100,100)

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
im = ax.imshow(original_data, cmap="summer")


N = 89
x = np.random.randint(0,100,size=N)
y = np.random.randint(0,100,size=N)

random_sample = original_data[x,y]
sc = ax2.scatter(x,y,c=random_sample, cmap=im.cmap, norm=im.norm)

ax2.set_aspect("equal")
ax2.set(xlim=ax.get_xlim(), ylim=ax.get_ylim())

fig.colorbar(sc, ax=[ax,ax2], orientation="horizontal")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you are the best! this is literally the perfect example i was looking for. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to choose N numbers from 10,000 (100 x 100) unique points on the 2d plot. I assume you want without replacement. Then you can "unravel" them onto your x,y coordinate.

```
random_choices = np.random.choice(10000, size=N, replace=False)
x, y = np.unravel_index(random_choices, (100, 100))
```

You can use these indices to create your scatter plot and size points appropriately:

```
data = np.random.random((100, 100))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=data[y, x])
```

Comment: i still don't know sure how to plot that indices on the surface plot.

Comment: Well what you have on the right is really just a scatter plot. I don't know how your data is formatted so can't really tell you how to do it. But I will update with a generic execution.

Comment: just a scatter plot won't change the marker size based on the value of the data? and the data is just a 2-d numpy array

Comment: You can use the `s` argument to change the size of data points.

Comment: I also made a change to choose without replacement, which I commented on originally but didn't actually show.